# Virtuoso SQL query of a SPARQL query in iSQL

Tags: sparql, virtuoso

I was going through this [link](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfperfcost/), which uses `EXPLAIN()` to show us the SQL query that Virtuoso generates(uses internally) for the input SPARQL query. I tried it on my Virtuoso 7.x version and found that I get a different output. I am not able to understand the output fully. Would it be possible to explain what this output from iSQL means and how I would interpret a SQL query from this?

The SPARQL query is

```
SPARQL SELECT DISTINCT ?s FROM <http://dbpedia.org> WHERE {
?s a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Cricketer> . 
?s <http://dbpedia.org/property/testdebutyear> ?o . 
};
```

The output I get is

```
{ 
Subquery 27 
{ 
RDF_QUAD   3.2e+03 rows(s_1_2_t1.S)
 inlined  P =  #/testdebutyear  G =  #/dbpedia.org 
RDF_QUAD unq       0.8 rows (s_1_2_t0.S)
 inlined  P =  ##type  ,  S = s_1_2_t1.S ,  O =  #/Cricketer  ,  G =  #/dbpedia.org 
Distinct (s_1_2_t0.S)

After code:
      0: s :=  := artm s_1_2_t0.S
      4: BReturn 0
Subquery Select(s)
}

After code:
      0: s := Call __ro2sq (s)
      5: BReturn 0
Select (s)
}

20 Rows. -- 2 msec.
```

How do I find the SQL query in this case? Is there a command or link that I am missing?

Comment: This "feature" is not like standard EXPLAIN but more for development and debugging, i.e. it doesn't really show execution plans or the like.

Comment: I did try the EXPLAIN as well, I just was trying to understand the SPOG tables that Virtuoso has and the indexing schemes. Trying to work out if understanding the SQL query helps. So was looking to see how Virtuoso gets the right offsets to select instances of concepts.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your specific question, you might read [further down the same page you pointed to above](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfperfcost/#rdfperfcosttransanalyze), to where it talks specifically about how to "Translate a SPARQL query into the correspondent SQL."

This is also discussed [on another feature-specific page](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtTipsAndTricksAanalyzingSPARQLQuery).

(Also note, the sample output on both these pages came from Virtuoso 6.x, while you're running 7.x, so your output will likely still differ.)

Here's what I got from my local Virtuoso 7.2.4 (Commercial Edition) --

```
SQL> SET SPARQL_TRANSLATE ON ; 
SQL> SELECT DISTINCT ?s FROM <http://dbpedia.org> WHERE { ?s a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Cricketer> . ?s <http://dbpedia.org/property/testdebutyear> ?o . } ; 
SPARQL_TO_SQL_TEXT
LONG VARCHAR
_______________________________________________________________________________

 SELECT  __ro2sq ("s_1_2_rbc"."s") AS "s" FROM (SELECT DISTINCT "s_1_2_t0"."S" AS "s"
  FROM DB.DBA.RDF_QUAD AS "s_1_2_t0"
    INNER JOIN DB.DBA.RDF_QUAD AS "s_1_2_t1"
    ON (
      "s_1_2_t0"."S" = "s_1_2_t1"."S")
  WHERE
    "s_1_2_t0"."G" = __i2idn ( __bft( 'http://dbpedia.org' , 1))
    AND 
    "s_1_2_t0"."P" = __i2idn ( __bft( 'http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type' , 1))
    AND 
    "s_1_2_t0"."O" = __i2idn ( __bft( 'http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Cricketer' , 1))
    AND 
    "s_1_2_t1"."G" = __i2idn ( __bft( 'http://dbpedia.org' , 1))
    AND 
    "s_1_2_t1"."P" = __i2idn ( __bft( 'http://dbpedia.org/property/testdebutyear' , 1))
OPTION (QUIETCAST)) AS "s_1_2_rbc"

1 Rows. -- 3 msec.
SQL> SET SPARQL_TRANSLATE OFF ;
```

NOTE -- this feature is only available in the command-line iSQL; it is not found in the browser-based iSQL interface.

All that said... I strongly suggest you ask us your initial questions going forward, instead of likely getting distracted by [XY Problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  There's fairly little to understand about the single table of quad data (`DB.DBA.RDF_QUAD`), which has 2 full and 3 partial indexes by default, which are sufficient for most typical uses, [all as discussed in the documentation](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfperfrdfscheme/).

The [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://sourceforge.net/p/virtuoso/mailman/virtuoso-users/) is often a better resource for Virtuoso-specific questions than here, where you tend to get a fair amount of guessing responses.

(ObDisclaimer: I work for [OpenLink Software](https://www.openlinksw.com/), producer of [Virtuoso](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/).)

Comment: You are right, thinking out loud means that my actual question is more related to the underlying implementation of SPOG tables. How does one access it from a program? I know this is kind of a dumb question, but the issue is that I'd like to know how triple stores i.e. the ones which use an underlying relational table to store RDFs work.  My attempt at understanding them was by looking at how the SQL is generated. Is there any documentation on how Virtuoso parses and executes a query and how it knows which offsets to pick?

Comment: Programs access the [SPOG and other RDF tables](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfquadtables/) optimally via [SPARQL queries/commands](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfsparql/), which may be [issued within SQL connections](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfsparqlinline/). All that said, I'm wondering why you're pursuing this line of inquiry? Understanding how we've done things in Virtuoso may not help you understand any other implementation… So what is your actual goal? (And what do mean by "which offsets to pick?")

Comment: You are right, it differs for a Jena TDB or SDB and my goal is to understand how these underlying tables/ structures help estimating the results of a query and how accurate they are. Line of inquiry starts from this paper http://www.csd.uoc.gr/~hy561/papers/storageaccess/optimization/Characteristic%20Sets.pdf and the related work mentioned for query estimation i.e. Stocker et.al. The reason for offset question is because I assumed that all instances of Cricketer would be stored from some offset. Maybe that was a wrong assumption.

Comment: Again all I want to do is to understand how each of these triple stores vary and the fact that I use Virtuoso 'virtually' all the time means that I'd want to understand why it is good or not good and the same goes for every other system too.

Comment: Internal storage and query optimizations are very complex questions. You may benefit from exploring some of our [blog posts](https://www.openlinksw.com/blog/vdb/blog/) and [whitepapers](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/white-papers/). I suggest particular focus on discussions of Benchmarking, Column-store vs Row-store, and Cluster Sharding/Partitioning.