# How to see SPARQL query plan

Tags: sparql, rdf, virtuoso, apache-jena, sparqlwrapper

We use `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to view a SQL query plan.

If there any equivalent of it is available for SPARQL query?

Comment: Possibly answered sufficiently by [Virtuoso SQL query of a SPARQL query in iSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40370880/virtuoso-sql-query-of-a-sparql-query-in-isql)?

Comment: [Jena ARQ](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/explain.html), [Blazegraph](https://wiki.blazegraph.com/wiki/index.php/Explain), [GraphDB](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/explain-plan.html)

Comment: Are the SQL and SPARQL query plans shown using the same syntax (e.g., INNER JOIN)?

Comment: BTW, you have never accepted any answer to your questions.

Comment: I read your question to say that Virtuoso was the target SPARQL endpoint, but maybe not?  If Virtuoso is indeed the target, have you read the Q&A to which I linked?  Or the documentation to which it links?